# What would you do instead of git switch -c [new branch] in versions of git before git switch was added?

Tags: git

I wanted to run `git switch -c [new branch name]`.

Unfortunately, I have discovered that I'm using a version of git older than when that was added.

I'm worried I'll accidently lose my progress when switching to a new branch.

How would I do this switch when using an older version of git?

Comment: `git checkout -b [new-branch-name]`. Do not be worried about losing progress when switching branches.

Comment: Maybe the documentation for `git switch` is unclear? It’s an experimental which replaces some use-cases for `git checkout`.

Answer (score -3):

I think I figured it out

```
git stash
git checkout -b [new branch]
git stash pop
```

Comment: There's no need for the stash

Comment: `git checkout -b` changes no files; it only makes a new branch label at the current HEAD.  Any uncommited and/or staged changes stay exactly as they were